# index.php // Silence is golden in every folder?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

Should I include a index.php with //silence is golden to every folder in my plugin? even css, js and images folders? Or is it just folders that contain code/ php files that should have the index.php file in it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This article from InMotion explains why such file exists: [Silence is Golden](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/blog/silence-is-golden/).

Quoting here the relevant parts in case the link goes down in the future:

> The entire file is a placeholder. Whenever someone visits a web page, the server attempts to run index.php or index.html. If you take a look at your site directory’s index.php, you’ll see the code that generates a WordPress site.

> Without index.php, anyone could just visit your site’s /wp-content folder and see all of the media, files, and directories it contains.

> The index.php file functions like a privacy screen: it blocks visitors from directly accessing your directories.

Or you can use below code in your .htaccess file to prevent directory listings even if that index.php file is not present:

```
Options –Indexes
```

Comment: In the article it says "Without index.php, anyone could just visit your site’s /wp-content folder and see all of the media, files, and directories it contains." 

So basically every folder you don't want people to be able to see the content of...right?

Comment: Correct, @HerrKingsley.

Comment: Manish, please avoid link-only answers. The URL might be removed in the future and people won't be able to read the solution to the problem. I edited your question to include the relevant parts of the referenced article so your answer remains useful even if the InMotion website were to dissapear.

Comment: @cabrerahector Noted Thank you